# Value of $\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\sin 2\theta}{\sin \theta} \right)^n \sin((m+1) \theta) \sin \theta d \theta$ on $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Define

$$f(m,n) = \int_0^{2 \pi} \left( \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{\sin \theta} \right)^n \sin((m+1) \theta) \sin \theta d \theta.$$

I want to find a nice formula for the value of $f(m,n)$ in terms of $m$, $n$ for tuples $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^2$.

I'm struggling to manipulate the integrand in a way to evaluate the integral, indeed, [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) fails to find an antiderivative (although that is trying to solve the more general problem $(m, n) \in \mathbb{R}^2$)

Here are the values of $f(m,n)$ for small $m$, $n$:

\begin{array} {rr|rrrr} && & &m & &\\  & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\n & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ & 3 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ & 4 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array}

Note I know for a fact that $f(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ for $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^2$, as can be seen in the table. (This integral arises as a certain inner product of two representations of a certain group.)

But I'm struggling to see much more than that. It appears $f(m,m)=1$ for all $m$ and $f(m,n)=0$ for $m>n$ as well as when $m+n$ is odd.

But other than that, I'm really not sure. What could I do to determine $f(m,n)$ for more values?

Comment: Consulting [Tables of Integrals Series and Products : pdf file](http://drhuang.com/science/mathematics/book/Table%20of%20Integrals,Series%20and%20Products%20Eighth%20Edition.pdf) section 3.612,  
page 393 (page 420/1156 in the pdf file), it looks like it is on point, since it *looks like* your integrand
can be converted into a group of terms, each of which is of form $~\sin(ax) \,\cos(bx).$  One verification idea is to try to develop a recursive formula through integration by parts for the *indefinite integral*, and then apply it to the $~[0,2\pi]~$ interval.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
&  \int_0^{2 \pi} \left( \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{\sin \theta} \right)^n \sin[(m+1) \theta] \sin \theta d \theta\\
= &\int_0^{2 \pi} \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\cos[(n-2k)\theta ]\sin[(m+1) \theta] \sin \theta d \theta\\
=&\  \frac14 \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk\int_0^{2 \pi}
\left(\cos[(n+m-2k)\theta]+ \cos[(n-m-2k)\theta]\right.\\
&\hspace{10mm}\left.  -\cos[(n+m+2-2k)\theta]-\cos[(n-m-2-2k)\theta]\right)d\theta\\
=& \ \frac\pi2\left[\binom n{\frac{n+m}2} +\binom n{\frac{n-m}2}-\binom n{\frac{n+m+2}2}-\binom n{\frac{n-m-2}2}\right]
\end{align}
where $n\pm m$ are even; otherwise the integral vanishes. The result produces the table
\begin{array} {rr|rrrr} && & &m & &\\  & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\n & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ & 3 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ & 4 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array}

Comment: How does one calculate by hand $\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}}$, $\binom{n}{\frac{3}{2}}$ etc...?

Comment: @Efesto - Edited the answer to clarify

Comment: @Efesto In general you must use the definition of binomial coefficient where instead of factorials you use the Gamma function $n!= \Gamma(n-1)$

Comment: @Quanto: you're often too fast for my. How do you get (I presume) the identity $(2\cos \theta)^n=\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}\cos((n-2k)\theta)$? I am sure there is an obvious argument I can't see at the moment.

Comment: @Mittens - here it is $$( 2\cos \theta)^n=(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})^n
= \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk e^{i(n-k)\theta} e^{-ik\theta}\\
= \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \cos(n-2k)\theta
$$

Comment: @Quanto: (+1) Thanks! I suspected that much, but it is nice to see it from your pen (or rather keyboard).

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\left(2x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)}\right)^{n}\sin\left(\left(m+1\right)x\right)\sin\left(x\right)dx=\\
\displaystyle2^{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos\left(x\right)^{n}\sin\left(\left(m+1\right)x\right)\sin\left(x\right)dx=\\
\displaystyle2\cdot2^{n}\int_{-1}^{1}x^{n}\sin\left(\left(m+1\right)\arccos\left(x\right)\right)dx=\\
\displaystyle2^{n}\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{m+n}\right)\cdot2\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\sin\left(\left(m+1\right)\arccos\left(x\right)\right)dx=\\
\displaystyle2^{n}\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{m+n}\right)\cdot2\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}U_m\left(x\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}dx=\\
\displaystyle2^{n}\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{m+n}\right)\cdot2\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\floor{\frac{m}{2}}}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{m-k}{k}\left(2x\right)^{m-2k}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}dx=\\
\displaystyle2^{n}\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{m+n}\right)\cdot2\sum_{k=0}^{\floor{\frac{m}{2}}}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{m-k}{k}2^{m-2k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\left(n+m-2k\right)}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}dx=\\
\displaystyle2^{n}\left(1+\left(-1\right)^{m+n}\right)\cdot2\sum_{k=0}^{\floor{\frac{m}{2}}}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{m-k}{k} 2^{m-2k}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+m-2k+1}{2}\right)}{4\Gamma\left(2+\frac{n+m-2k}{2}\right)}=\\
\displaystyle\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m+n}+1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\cdot  2^{m+n}\sum_{k=0}^{\floor{\frac{m}{2}}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{4^{k}}\binom{m-k}{k}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+m-2k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2+\frac{n+m-2k}{2}\right)}\\
\displaystyle=\pi\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+m}+1}{2}\left[\binom{n}{\floor{\frac{n-m}{2}}}-\binom{n}{\floor{\frac{n-m}{2}}-1}\right]\end{array}$$

Where:

- $U_m(z)$ is the Chebyshev Polynomial of the Second Kind

---

$$\bbox[15px,#E0EFFF,border:5px groove #0058B3]{f(m,n)=\pi\cdot\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+m}+1}{2}\left[\binom{n}{\floor{\frac{n-m}{2}}}-\binom{n}{\floor{\frac{n-m}{2}}-1}\right]}$$

Comment: (+1) It is nice to see orthogonal polynomials at play.